# Changing ViewModel based on user

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an API in Asp Net Core and I want to change the response of a call based on the user that is calling.

For example we have two clients

SuperClientDoesManyThings

PublicClient

I have a UserViewModel with all the data from the user.

Like

UserViewModel

- Name
- Address
- SuperSecretNoOneCanSee

If the client is SuperClientDoesManyThings I want to Pass the UserViewModel without any changes.

If the client is PublicClient I want to hide SuperSecretNoOneCanSee, preferably without rewriting UserViewModel (I want to avoid repetitions)

Comment: Make one Client class with a boolean SuperUser property. Default false. Switch if it is true.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you are actually talking about serialization. You have a 'ViewModel':

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string SuperSecretNoOneCanSee { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller you set the values, based on the calling client. For *PublicClient* you should omit `SuperSecretNoOneCanSee`. If you have defined different scopes for both clients, then you can do something like:

```
var isPublicClient = User.HasClaim("scope", "PublicClient");
if (isPublicClient)
    return new UserViewModel { Name = "my name", Address = "my address" };
else
    return new UserViewModel { Name = "my name", Address = "my address", SuperSecretNoOneCanSee = "secret" };
```

This may result in the following string for *PublicClient*:

```
{ "Name": "my name", "Address": "my address", "SuperSecretNoOneCanSee": null }
```

Or:

```
{ "Name": "my name", "Address": "my address" }
```

This depends on the json serializer settings.

In the first case you can see that the field exists, but it never has a value. In the second case you won't see it exists. But it really doesn't matter. The bottom line is that you don't have to actually remove the field from the viewmodel.

Comment: Its exactly that the Idea I'm trying to acomplish. But I wanted to do it a little more globally, like a filter.I just don't know exactly how at this moment.

Actually I have a Model that comes from EntityFramework. It gets mapped using Automapper to the `UserViewModel` in the controller. 

I'm thinking about making a conditional mapping based on user claim.

Comment: Then you are talking about authorization. I suggest you look at the different types of authorization, like Claims-based, Resource-based and View-based. I suggest you read the documents here to get some ideas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data

Comment: I've read it many times now. What I want is more like that: Every requests passes a middleware. If the client has the right scope it does nothing. If not, it nullifies every property that he has no authorization. Is it possible? These seem to unauthorize the entire request

Comment: You can query the database (including all fields) and find some way to map the authorized fields only to the viewmodel. E.g. you can create an attribute where you define the level of authorization (on the property in the ViewModel). With reflection you can map the fields, based on the authorization level in the attribute.

Comment: Another, more difficult approach would be to build an Expression, selecting only those fields that are allowed according to the attribute.

Comment: I think I'll build a Resource Filter that reads the object and sets every property null that a user shouldn't have access based on an attribute